# Preview with Custom Post Type Not Working

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, debug

At this point I have tried everything I know to fix the issue.

Issue: preview only works right after a custom posts is loaded or updated. If you make any changes or hit preview twice without updating the preview 404s. Pages and blog post do not 404 the previews.

We were using the ACF and CPUI plugins and roots theme. I have turned off all the plugins, switch to the 2014 theme, add the CPT manually, and Update WP core.

We have a lot of Custom post types in our site and rebuilding would be a huge pain.

Has anyone dealt with this issues? Anything helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you walk us through the situations where the preview works and where it doesn't work? What do you mean by "right after a custom posts is loaded or updated"? Are you having issues with Pages or Posts?

Comment: Following up on that, would you link to the CPUI plugin?

Comment: Preview works: Pages and Posts.
Preview Doesn't work: Custom Post Types - When you click preview it 404s whenever you add anything to be previewed, but haven't saved or clicked update.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Try disabling pretty URLs to see if something with the rewrite rules is messing with it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the parameter that you can pass to the `supports` argument is `post_formats`, removing this argument will fix the problem with the preview redirecting to a wrong or non-existing url.
Code sample:

```
    if ( ! function_exists('custom_post_type') ) {

    // Register Custom Post Type
    function custom_post_type() {

        // some code

        $args = array(
            // 'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'post-formats', 'comments', 'sticky'),
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'comments', 'sticky'),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'your_cpt_pictures', 'your_cpt_updates', 'your_cpt_outline' ),
            'capability_type'     => 'post'
        );
        register_post_type( 'your_cpt', $args );

    }

    // Hook into the 'init' action
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using CPT UI and ACF. To resolve the issue i went into CPT UI > Edit Post Types and disabled support for Post Formats

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue, if anyone used **CPT UI** to create them, turn on REVISIONS to fix the problem, this managed to fix the issue for me. Latest WP 5.7 & CPT UI.